# Client Side Validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a field on an asp.net page for which I have used `RequiredFieldValidator`.

```
<tr> 
  <td align="left" style="width: 130px"> 
    <asp:Label ID="LblPagename" runat="server" Text="Page Name " CssClass="label"></asp:Label><font 
      color="red"> *</font> 
  </td> 
  <td align="left" style="width: 1087px" class="layout-grid"> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtPageName" runat="server" MaxLength="50" ></asp:TextBox> 
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" 
      ValidationGroup="Save" ControlToValidate="TxtPageName" ForeColor="Red"
      ErrorMessage="Please enter Page Name."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>  
  </td> 
</tr>
```

on save I am allowing `CauseValidation="true"` for the the same `ValidationGroup` as mentioned above

```
<tr> 
  <td colspan="3" align="center" style="width: 1193px"> 
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnMenu" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="Save" ImageUrl="~/Images/Save.png"  
      runat="server" OnClick="btnMenu_Click" OnClientClick="SaveFunctionalities();"/> 
    &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancelMenu" ImageUrl="~/Images/btnCancel.png" runat="server" 
      OnClick="btnCancelMenu_Click" /> 
  </td> 
</tr>
```

But on save, along with the error message for the empty field, the save is being called.

The same thing is working fine on other pages.

The only difference is that here I have a javascript function call on `OnClientClick`.

Is that causing some problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that `SaveFunctionalities();` returns a boolean value, depending on whether an error has occured or not.  If everything is fine, then return `true` - if there are any errors return `false`.

Then update your OnClientClick to pass that return variable to the button..

```
OnClientClick="return SaveFunctionalities();"
```

If there are no problems, the button will continue as normal via the `true` value.  If there are errors, then it will be told to stop processing via the `false` value.

**UPDATE**

From the code posted in the comment by @Richa, you are always returning `false`, no matter what the validation returns.

Your function should look more like this...

```
function SaveFunctionalities() {
  if (Page_ClientValidate()) {
    ...
    return true;
  } else {
    return false; 
  }
}
```

Comment: I made the following changes in the JS function:function SaveFunctionalities() { if (Page_ClientValidate()) { var ddl = document.getElementById("<%=lbMenu.ClientID%>"); var hdn = document.getElementById("<%=hdnRight.ClientID%>"); hdn.value = ""; for (var i = 0; i < ddl.options.length; i++) { hdn.value += ddl.options[i].value + ","; } } return false; }                                                                              and call was modified as:OnClientClick="return SaveFunctionalities();      still not the save method is being hit.Where am i going wrong now?

Comment: @Richa, let me double check... do you want btnMenu to post-back to the server **if** the standard validation on the page reports NO errors?

Comment: I want btnMenu to call the btnMenu_Click (cs method) only when all the validations have been passed..i.e. no fields are empty..SaveFunctionalities just saves the values in a hidden field..if that is called ..it's okay..

Comment: @Richa, that is as I thought. In that case, you still haven't fully followed my suggestion, because your function is return `false` for **everything**... I will update my answer now to show you what it should be like